# dynamic for loops for generating combinations in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Suppose I have 2 variables , "a" and "b". I need to generate all kinds of combinations of "a 0.1 b 0.1" all the way up to "a 0.3 b 0.3". I can easily do it by recursive nested for loops in R.

```
A =1
for (i in seq(0.1, 0.3, by = 0.1)) {
  for (j in seq(0.1, 0.3, by = 0.1)) {
      B = paste("a", i , "b", j)
      A = c(A, B) 
  }
}
A = A[-1]
A
```

My output will be

```
> A
[1] "a 0.1 b 0.1" "a 0.1 b 0.2" "a 0.1 b 0.3" "a 0.2 b 0.1" "a 0.2 b 0.2" "a 0.2 b 0.3" "a 0.3 b 0.1" "a 0.3 b 0.2" "a 0.3 b 0.3"
```

If I have 3 variables, then I have to include one more for loop.

```
A =1
for (i in seq(0.1, 0.3 , by = 0.1)) {
  for (j in seq(0.1, 0.3, by = 0.1)) {
    for (k in seq(0.1, 0.3, by = 0.1)) {
      B = paste("a", i , "b", j, "c",k)
      A = c(A, B) 
    }
  }
}
A = A[-1]
A
> A
 [1] "a 0.1 b 0.1 c 0.1" "a 0.1 b 0.1 c 0.2" "a 0.1 b 0.1 c 0.3" "a 0.1 b 0.2 c 0.1" "a 0.1 b 0.2 c 0.2" "a 0.1 b 0.2 c 0.3"
 [7] "a 0.1 b 0.3 c 0.1" "a 0.1 b 0.3 c 0.2" "a 0.1 b 0.3 c 0.3" "a 0.2 b 0.1 c 0.1" "a 0.2 b 0.1 c 0.2" "a 0.2 b 0.1 c 0.3"
[13] "a 0.2 b 0.2 c 0.1" "a 0.2 b 0.2 c 0.2" "a 0.2 b 0.2 c 0.3" "a 0.2 b 0.3 c 0.1" "a 0.2 b 0.3 c 0.2" "a 0.2 b 0.3 c 0.3"
[19] "a 0.3 b 0.1 c 0.1" "a 0.3 b 0.1 c 0.2" "a 0.3 b 0.1 c 0.3" "a 0.3 b 0.2 c 0.1" "a 0.3 b 0.2 c 0.2" "a 0.3 b 0.2 c 0.3"
[25] "a 0.3 b 0.3 c 0.1" "a 0.3 b 0.3 c 0.2" "a 0.3 b 0.3 c 0.3"
>
```

But what if my variables(a,b) and my range (0.1 to 0.3) are dynamic? Is there any method of dynamically generating for loops? Or any better way to address this problem?

Comment: Hello Sriram, welcome to stack overflow. Maybe the expand.grid function is helpfull in this situation(https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/expand.grid.html).

Comment: I suggest that you look up an odometer-like approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -

```
var1 <- paste("a",seq(0.1, 0.3, by = 0.1),sep=" ")
var2 <- paste("b",seq(0.1, 0.3, by = 0.1),sep=" ")
var3 <- paste("c",seq(0.1, 0.3, by = 0.1),sep=" ")
vars <- list(var1,var2,var3)

do.call(paste, as.data.frame(expand.grid(vars), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

**Output**

```
[1] "a 0.1 b 0.1 c 0.1" "a 0.2 b 0.1 c 0.1" "a 0.3 b 0.1 c 0.1" "a 0.1 b 0.2 c 0.1"
 [5] "a 0.2 b 0.2 c 0.1" "a 0.3 b 0.2 c 0.1" "a 0.1 b 0.3 c 0.1" "a 0.2 b 0.3 c 0.1"
 [9] "a 0.3 b 0.3 c 0.1" "a 0.1 b 0.1 c 0.2" "a 0.2 b 0.1 c 0.2" "a 0.3 b 0.1 c 0.2"
[13] "a 0.1 b 0.2 c 0.2" "a 0.2 b 0.2 c 0.2" "a 0.3 b 0.2 c 0.2" "a 0.1 b 0.3 c 0.2"
[17] "a 0.2 b 0.3 c 0.2" "a 0.3 b 0.3 c 0.2" "a 0.1 b 0.1 c 0.3" "a 0.2 b 0.1 c 0.3"
[21] "a 0.3 b 0.1 c 0.3" "a 0.1 b 0.2 c 0.3" "a 0.2 b 0.2 c 0.3" "a 0.3 b 0.2 c 0.3"
[25] "a 0.1 b 0.3 c 0.3" "a 0.2 b 0.3 c 0.3" "a 0.3 b 0.3 c 0.3"
```

**Explanation**

`var1`,`var2`,`var3` have been designed just for example's sake.

Use the `expand.grid()` to pass a `list` for variables like `vars`.

The `vars` can contain the `list` of variables that you dynamically generate the combinations out of.

Comment: working perfectly fine. I created a loop for creating var 1 ... var n , where n is task specific.                                                                                                        vars <- vector("list", n)        
for(i in 1:n){
  vars[i] <- list(paste(letters[i],seq(0.1, 0.4, by = 0.1), sep=" "))
}                                                                                                                       where n is user defined.